# How to make regex to enforce comma between every word?

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

I am writing a C# ASP.NET MVC application and I need to enforce some rules for user input.

In a form a user can write some incident case numbers which is on the form IRxxxxxx where x can be a number (0-9). I would like to make a regex that checks that the input can consist of either exactly one case number or multiple seperated by a commas (and some possible whitespace before and after the commas). I have tried a couple of things, but is not able to get it right.

Valid inputs could be:

- IR123456
- IR123456,IR123456,IR123456 (and so on)
- IR123456, IR123456,IR123456 (notice the space after the first comma)

Invalid inputs could be:

- IR123
- IR1234567
- ir123456
- IR123456,,IR123456

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why hasn't it met your requirements/where are you getting stuck?

Comment: My best bet so far is (IR[0-9]{6},?)*IR[0-9]{6} which works for IR123456,IR123456,IR123456 but not with spaces before or after the comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work in most Regex engines:

```
^IR\d{6}(,\s?IR\d{6})*$
```

This looks for "IR" followed by any 6 digits. If there are additional IDs, this makes sure that there is a comma following the preceding one (with an optional space).

<sup>[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ZRqUKr/1)</sup>

Comment: Hello, This works, but what would it look like if there could be any number of spaces before and after the commas so strings like "IR123456 ,     IR123456" also would be matched? :)

Comment: Hello, the regex ^IR\d{6}(\s*,\s*?IR\d{6})*$ works just like i want it, thank you for the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex: ^((^|,)\s*IR\d{6})+$

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the answer, but it is not quite what i am after as it does not match the whole string "IR123456, IR123456, IR123456" but only the IR123456 numbers.